# Grub - are both disks bootable in my server with Debian 7.1 and software Raid1?

Tags: debian, boot, grub, raid1

I've a problem with one of my two disks of a raid1 software (ovh dedicated server with O.S. Debian 7.1). It will be replaced in a few days. 
My question is how to check with Grub if both disks are bootable. I'd like to know that after software rebuilding of raid1 by mdadm, the server will boot without problems.

I can add some information:

1) I have Bios and not Uefi

2) This is the text of the grub configuration file "grub.cfg"

```
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then   
load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then

set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"

save_env saved_entry

set prev_saved_entry=

save_env prev_saved_entry

set boot_once=true

fi

function savedefault {

if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then

saved_entry="${chosen}"

save_env saved_entry

fi

}

function load_video {

insmod vbe

insmod vga

insmod video_bochs

insmod video_cirrus

}

insmod raid

insmod mdraid09

insmod part_gpt

insmod part_gpt

insmod ext2

set root='(mduuid/9bad0377260a5b69a4d2adc226fd5302)'

search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root adcd0e04-e6ee-4a7d-abd2-a8880e6ba90d

if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then

set gfxmode=640x480

load_video

insmod gfxterm

insmod raid

insmod mdraid09

insmod part_gpt

insmod part_gpt

insmod ext2

set root='(mduuid/9bad0377260a5b69a4d2adc226fd5302)'

search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root adcd0e04-e6ee-4a7d-abd2-a8880e6ba90d

set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale

set lang=

insmod gettext

fi

terminal_output gfxterm

set timeout=5

set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue

set menu_color_highlight=white/blue

menuentry "Debian GNU/Linux, OVH kernel 3.8.13-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64" {

insmod raid

insmod mdraid09

insmod part_gpt

insmod part_gpt

insmod ext2

set root='(mduuid/9bad0377260a5b69a4d2adc226fd5302)'

search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root adcd0e04-e6ee-4a7d-abd2-a8880e6ba90d

linux /boot/bzImage-3.8.13-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 root=/dev/md2 ro quiet

}

if [ -f $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then

source $prefix/custom.cfg;

fi
```

3) By the execution of a script I downloaded (bootscriptinfo) I had these output:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================
=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.


sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       linux_raid_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       linux_raid_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       linux_raid_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       linux_raid_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

md3: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

md2: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/md2 already mounted or MDRaid/md2 busy

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 3,907,029,167 3,907,029,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1              40         2,048         2,009 BIOS Boot partition
/dev/sda2           4,096   307,202,047   307,197,952 RAID partition (Linux)
/dev/sda3     307,202,048 3,845,582,847 3,538,380,800 RAID partition (Linux)
/dev/sda4   3,845,582,848 3,907,020,799    61,437,952 Swap partition (Linux)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 3,907,029,167 3,907,029,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1              40         2,048         2,009 BIOS Boot partition
/dev/sdb2           4,096   307,202,047   307,197,952 RAID partition (Linux)
/dev/sdb3     307,202,048 3,845,582,847 3,538,380,800 RAID partition (Linux)
/dev/sdb4   3,845,582,848 3,907,020,799    61,437,952 Swap partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/md2         adcd0e04-e6ee-4a7d-abd2-a8880e6ba90d   ext4       
/dev/md3         adfbad7d-c8c3-4b04-884a-87d2d35e3a62   ext4       
/dev/sda2        9bad0377-260a-5b69-a4d2-adc226fd5302   linux_raid_member 
/dev/sda3        cca07bac-0ea8-99e8-a4d2-adc226fd5302   linux_raid_member 
/dev/sda4        05de1987-d6cb-4baa-87f8-3b008e05de8e   swap       
/dev/sdb2        9bad0377-260a-5b69-a4d2-adc226fd5302   linux_raid_member 
/dev/sdb3        cca07bac-0ea8-99e8-a4d2-adc226fd5302   linux_raid_member 
/dev/sdb4        7b1315b8-dcf4-4bd6-9379-ffbcf3014aa6   swap       


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

  No volume groups found
```

4) By examining the file group.cfg  I remarked these two lines that by the uuid identify before the partitions sda2 and sdb2 and after (in the second line) md2.

```
set root='(mduuid/9bad0377260a5b69a4d2adc226fd5302)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root adcd0e04-e6ee-4a7d-abd2-a8880e6ba90d
```

5) By examing the output of bootscriptinfo I remarked two details:

The first one:

```
=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
```

The second one:

```
  The first parttion of both disks is dedicated to a Bios Boot Partition and only for sdb1 there is this value in Boot Sector type
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
Core.img is a file in the same folder of grub.cfg (\boot\grub). Why does it appear only in sdb1?
```

I hope that this information will be enough in order to have some answers to my questions.

Comment: Please edit your post and indent the script block(s) (select all the lines, press `{}` in the menu) then remove all this space wasting extra lines that make your post difficult to read. And while you are at it, remove the Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Anthon "And while you are at it, remove the"?

Comment: @FaheemMitha "And while you are at it, remove the: 'Thanks in advance for your help' "

Comment: @Anthon Ah, sorry. I misunderstood what you wrote.

Comment: To start with, check that GRUB2 is installed on both your disks. See the second answer by benrifkah in https://serverfault.com/questions/61400/how-do-i-tell-if-grub-is-installed-on-a-device

Comment: Sorry, no useful. I already saw it